# Respon with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

im using ionic view legacy and the http post don't have any problem about it. but when migrating using ionic view pro when doing http post then show error "**Respon with status: 0 for URL: null**".

This is a part of my config.xml

```html
    <access origin="*" subdomain="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
   
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^1.1.9">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="-" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="auto" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
```

this problem because of CORS so at back end i just add :

```html
/* Allow from any origin */
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
  }
```

but problem still not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally… i solve this problem with change from http to https and check header send. Headher from jwt is my problem, so i change it using post not header.