# Response with status:0 for URL:null when i am making a rest from ios ionic app

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am making a rest call from ionic app and its working in android device but not in the ios device.
This is how i am making a rest call from my ionic service.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class loginService {
    constructor(private http : Http){ }
    getAllUsers(authData){
        console.log(authData);
        return this.http.post('http://Some IP add:8080/api/customerr/getUser', authData);
    }
}
```

This is how I am receiving the data in my login.ts file

```
this.loginservice.getAllUsers(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((response) => {
    this.loginResponse = response.json()
} (err)=>{
    alert(err)
});
```

Comment: whats the error message? Could you show any error log showing?

Comment: Response with status: 0 for URL:null

Comment: what you getting in console in case of IOs?

Comment: I am just getting the above error in alert popup.

Answer (score 1):

Finally… I solved this problem by changing the API URL call from "http://yourapiurl/" to "https://yourapiurl/" and That sounds good. Please try this one.

I got this from here,
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397111/respon-with-status-0-for-url-null)

Thank you.